# rich:select inside rich:column not showing values

Tags: richfaces

I have the following structure in my jspx

```
<rich:dataTable var="row"...
    <rich:column>
        <rich:select value="#{row.currentValue}" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{SessionBean.AllPosibleValues}" />
        </rich:select>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

AllPosibleValues is a List of SelectItem objects, with label and value properties setted.

I want to display the current value for this column, (fetched from database) and allow the user to change it, by using a combobox. The problem is that the values are not loaded, and the comboboxes are showed unselected, as if `#{row.selectedValue}` were null.

If the rich:select is outside the `<datatable>`, the values are displayed well, **so the problem appears to be the nesting of `<column>` and `<select>` tags**.

I believe it is a known issue, but I don't know if there is a workaround, or another way to do that I want. Any idea?

Comment: Works for me, have you checked if the datatypes and values match? What version of RichFaces are you using?

Comment: I'm using Richfaces 4.0.1. The datatypes match, they are Long values.

Comment: It's possible that it doesn't work in older versions, you can try supplying something else than SelectItem.